# Filtering a TreeView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use the code below for filtering a treeview. Can this be improved?

```
private IEnumerable<TreeNode> FindNodeByValue(TreeNodeCollection nodes, string searchstring)
 {


    foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        if (node.Value.IndexOf(searchstring,
              StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            yield return node;
        else
        {
            foreach (var subNode in FindNodeByValue(node.ChildNodes, searchstring))
                yield return subNode;
        }
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var query= FindNodeByValue(TreeView1.Nodes, fieldFilterTxtBx.Text);
    if (query != null)
    {
        //TreeView1.Nodes[0].Expand();
        //TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();
        foreach (TreeNode node in query.ToList())
        {
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node);

        }


        //  TreeNode newnode = new TreeNode("Detail Engineering");
        // TreeView1.Nodes.Add(newnode);

        TreeView1.ExpandAll();
    }

    else
    {

        Label1.Text = "No file found";

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh and populate"?  Do you want to clear the list and just show matching nodes? Do you want to just jump to the matching node and expand down to it?

Comment: i need clear the list and just show matching nodes after button click

Answer (score 2):

What's the problem with your implementation? You clear the tree and add new (filtered) nodes. Somehow, `TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();` is under comment, so it may be supposed that you want to preserve full node structure. If so, just store it in memory:

```
var query = FindNodeByValue(PersistentNodeSet.Nodes, fieldFilterTxtBx.Text);
if (query != null)
{
    TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();
    foreach (TreeNode node in query.ToList())
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
    TreeView1.ExpandAll();
}
```

And if you want the tree to preserve original structure, you need to use recursion in `FindNodeByValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Button1_Click**

- The var `query` can't be null. So replace it with `if (query.Any())`
- There is no need to call `ToList()` you can just iterate over the items.

  ```
  foreach (TreeNode node in query)
  {
      TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node);

  }
  ```

  but basically it doesn't make much sense, because first you search in `TreeView1.Nodes` and then you add the found items again to the treeview.
- If you reverse the logic of the `if` condition, you can save some horizontal spacing.

  ```
  if (!query.Any())
  {
      Label1.Text = "No file found";
      return;
  }

  foreach (TreeNode node in query.ToList())
  {
      TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
  }

  TreeView1.ExpandAll();
  ```

**General remarks**

- You should use braces `{}` for single `if` statements and loops, for your code to be less errorprone.
- Dead code should be deleted